# Are families of real analytic functions equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, functional-analysis

1) Let $f_n:I \to \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be a family of functions on an Interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. If all functions are real analytic, i.e. identical to their Taylor series expansion near every point of $I$, does this imply that the family is equicontinuous? One may assume $I$ to be bounded or even compact here.

2) If not, do you know any useful theorems under which additional assumptions this could be true?

Comment: What about $f_n(x)=nx$, $I=[0,1]$?

Comment: Remember that equicontinuity is a condition on a _family_ of functions.  If the functions in that family have nothing to do with each other, then you probably won't have equicontinuity.  Anyway, if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on a compact set, then $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example: take $I = [0,1]$ and $f_n(x) = x^n$.  These are real analytic and even uniformly bounded, but not equicontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the family is bounded and holomorphic on an open region in the complex plane that contains the closure of $I$, then you have equicontinuity by Cauchy estimates on the derivative.

Comment: No, that's not true.  For example, $f_n(x) = \sin(nx)$ are not equicontinuous.  What you would need to use Cauchy estimates is analyticity and uniform boundedness on a region of the complex plane containing your (compact) interval.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for spotting the error!